# Woocommerce checkout page: remove view cart button & other messages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

First, I'm a bit of a noob.  I'm not a web developer/programmer.  But I'm also not an idiot and have played with functions.php (just a little bit).

here is the page:

https://tefl-online-course.com/checkout-lp/?add-to-cart=228

When users click on a link on my Landing Page it adds the product to the cart automatically and takes them to the checkout page.

Now, I would like to do the following.

1. Remove/hide the "View Cart" button.  This is the most important...I don't want people leaving this checkout page.
2. I wouldn't mind removing all of the messages: a. successfully added to cart.  b. returning customer & c. have a coupon but not hugely important.

Comment: just use css `.woocommerce-message, .woocommerce-info { display:none; }`

Comment: Would be better to hook into woocommerce somehow.

Answer (score 0):

For the add to cart message :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'remove_message_after_add_to_cart', 99);

function remove_message_after_add_to_cart(){
    if( isset( $_GET['add-to-cart'] ) ){
        wc_clear_notices();
    }
}
```

For coupon and return customer , just disabled them on woocommerce options page

EDIT : Fix for lastest version (2.4.6)

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of woocommerce there is two ways:

You can hide from css or inside the woocommerce/include/wc-template-functions

```
function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');
```

From product page and single page both buttons will be remove immediately.

Thanks,
Tripathi

Answer (score 0):

Another way to hide the "View Cart" button is to add a "display:none" in the style.css of your child theme

Try the following :

```
.added_to_cart .wc-forward{
    display: none !important;
}
```

or

```
a.added_to_cart{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS in your wp-admin -> appearance -> customize -> custom css :

```
p.woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons.buttons a.button.wc-forward:first-child {display:none;}
```