# How to change position of woocommerce error messages on Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and would like to position the error message that user's get when they don't enter a required field underneath the form, just before the checkout button.

I tried adding this to my functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'wc_print_notices', 10  );
```

but that didn't change the error messages from appearing above the checkout formular.

Which action do I have to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit the location of the checkout errors you must do the following:

1. Set `SCRIPT_DEBUG` constant to true, do it in the *wp-config.php* file `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);`
2. Locate the *checkout.js* script in the *woocommerce/assets/js/frontend*
3. Locate `wc_checkout_form.$checkout_form.prepend( error_message );` around line 396
4. Change it to `wc_checkout_form.$order_review.append( error_message );`

Setting the `SCRIPT_DEBUG` to true effectively loads the development resource files rather then the minified production versions, allowing for easy manipulation.

This is not a perfect solution but it works. And now you know where the checkout errors are effectively set in the context of the DOM.

Comment: I know you said it's not a perfect solution, but I don't think it's a solution at all - editing core files that are just going to wipe your changes when WooCommerce updates!?

Comment: Also the performance hit from using non-minified scripts

Answer (score 8):

Sadly it seems like best way is with a jQuery event listener, the accepted answer is a really bad idea.

I also would have preferred a different way. At least this way you don't have to change the core files. And it's reasonably stable. Although a big update from WooCommerce can still break it in future if they would change the classnames.

Just be aware that if you try to put in the form itself it will go into a loop. So some extra checks might be needed in certain cases

```
$('form.checkout.woocommerce-checkout').bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
  if ($('ul.woocommerce-error').length) {
    $('ul.woocommerce-error').insertAfter('form.checkout')//where you want to place 
  }
});
```

Comment: You might also be able to put the above into a shortcode to make it easier to position it on a page.

Comment: @Steve most likely you would want to put this in your theme / plugin so it always run, a shortcode will be depended on your users action.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript's MutationObserver feature.
Below code is for putting the error message above the checkout form. You may modify the logic as per your need.

```
    const destinationElement = document.querySelector( '.woocommerce-notices-wrapper' );
    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    const targetNode = document.forms.checkout;

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = { childList: true };

    // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    const callback = function(mutationsList) {
        for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
            let changedNode = mutation.addedNodes[0] ? mutation.addedNodes[0] : mutation.removedNodes[0];
            if ( changedNode && changedNode.classList.contains('woocommerce-NoticeGroup')) {
                destinationElement.innerHTML = mutation.addedNodes[0] ? mutation.addedNodes[0].innerHTML : '';
                if (mutation.addedNodes[0]) {
                    mutation.addedNodes[0].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to move it with CSS or physically move the piece of code that calls it into a different div - best to establish a Child Theme if you are going to edit core theme pages/css. There is a call to `wc-print_notices();` in `templates/checkout/cart-errors.php` which you could try putting in wherever you wanted it to print them together with the contents of the page which define the messages. Find the bit that calls the `cart-errors.php` page part. It should be a `wc_get_template('templates/cart-errors.php', .....)` call. See also `invludes/wc-form-handler.php function checkout_action()`

You might find `remove_action()` instead of `add_action()` works on `'wc_print_notices'` It may cause all sorts of problems though.

Reference
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

`wc_print_notices();` also appears in `templates/chckout/form-checkout.php` - you might also be able to manipulate it or move it there, with the same caveat as above.

The function itself lives in `/includes/wc-notice-functions.php`.
There is also `wc_get_notices()` which returns an array of error notices which can be echoed out wherever you want them.

This might also be a helpful pointer to the right way to get rid of unwanted messages
[@XciD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858926/xcid)  's answer - though OP said it didn't work `wc_clear_notices();` might be a useful pointer.

[Woocommerce checkout page: remove view cart button & other messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927419/woocommerce-checkout-page-remove-view-cart-button-other-messages?rq=1)