# How to show individual error on woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[Woocommerce checkout page error messages image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6jdw.png)

Currently woocommerce showing error as above shown in image. I want individual error message below each input box as shown in below image. Please help.

[Expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGrip.png)

Comment: try this link it will help you definitely, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33794083/2940521

Comment: @user2940521 thanks for your reply, I have check the above link u have given but it will only change the position of error messages, I want error message to be displayed below the each individual input box.

Comment: You will need to remove woocommerce' default validation and add your custom validation. Also, you will need to customize your form-billing.php template to accommodate custom error areas.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add PHP snippet and css.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'checkout_fields_in_label_error', 10, 4 );

function checkout_fields_in_label_error( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
   if ( strpos( $field, '</span>' ) !== false && $args['required'] ) {
      $error = '<span class="error" style="display:none">';
      $error .= sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), $args['label'] );
      $error .= '</span>';
      $field = substr_replace( $field, $error, strpos( $field, '</span>' ), 0);
   }
   return $field;
}
```

CSS:

```
.woocommerce-checkout p.woocommerce-invalid-required-field span.error {
   color: #e2401c;
   display: block !important;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: woocoomerce doesnt currently add this class to the erranous fields :(